# Make "Enter" key default button to "Save Tag Edits" within SO Teams

Tags: feature-request, tags, stack-overflow-for-teams

I had to recently modify a slew of tags within Stack Overflow for Teams.  When you edit the tag I would expect pressing the enter key would be the same as clicking "Save Tag Edits"; however it isn't.  This forces the user to use the mouse instead of the convenience of their keyboard.

Can we make it such that when you are focused on this input box the "Save Tag Edits" button becomes the default?

[image: tag editor]